# How to write a func to get first/second/third etc item from each iterables without using itertools?

Tags: python

I have a predefined function `lets(string)`:

```
def lets(string):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        yield string[i]
```

And I need to define alternate function which takes number of iterables:

```
def alternate(*args):
    ...
```

and using this function in these two ways suppose to product the result like the following:

```
' '.join([str(i) for i in alternate('abcde','fg','hijk')])
-->a f h b g i c j d k e

' '.join([str(i) for i in alternate(lets('abcde'),lets('fg'),lets('hijk'))])
-->a f h b g i c j d k e
```

I have tried multiple ways to define alternate by the knowledge I know so far, but I can never get it done, here is my closest version:

```
def alternate(*args):
    n=0
    while n in range(11):
        for i in args:
            try:
                yield list(i)[n]
            except :
                yield next(iter(i))
        n+=1
```

But it gives me:

```
' '.join([str(i) for i in alternate('abcde','fg','hijk')])
-> a f h b g i c f j d f k e f h a f h a f h a f h a f h a f h a f h 
' '.join([str(i) for i in alternate(lets('abcde'),lets('fg'),lets('hijk'))])
-> a f h
```

Can someone please help me with this, I am new to use python generator, really appreciated!

Comment: The [itertools recipe section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) has a `roundrobin()` function that does just this.

Comment: besides it's not the problem you asked about, but you can iterate over strings with a for loop like `for s in string:` an get `s` which is the character at a certain point

Answer (score 0):

The outer while loop should go through the number of times that maximum length of the args item is.

Then for every args item, you can yield only if there is a value. Checking if there is a value or not is gone with try-except part; however, it can also be controlled using basic if-else statement.

```
def alternate(*args):
    n=0
    while n in range(max(map(len, args))):
        for i in args:
            try:
                yield list(i)[n]
            except :
                pass
        n+=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a lot, but it only works on alternate('abcde','fg','hijk'). alternate(lets('abcde'),lets('fg'),lets('hijk')) will gives a TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len(). Is there a way to this without using len()?

Comment: If it is helpful, you can mark my answer as a correct solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
yield list(i)[n]
```

when i is a generator and not a list, the first time you call `list(i)` you will consume the generator. You should instead of converting to a list, just yield the next value:

```
yield next(i)
```

Comment: If I change it to yield next(i), it will raise StopIteration immediately.

Comment: @Saoish - wrap the statement in a try/except and ignore the exception.

Comment: Can you show me the actual codes? I tried what you said, but it turns out mass.